# (Java) How can I store my x and y values to use them outside of for loops?

Tags: java, for-loop, conways-game-of-life, storing-data

I'm coding Conway's Game of Life on Processing 3 and I want to store x and y so that the squares don't change right away, but I don't know how to store it to use later. Any help is appreciated!

```
void keyPressed() {

  for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++) {

    for (int y = 0; y < 30; y++) {

     int numNeighbours = numNeighbours(x,y);

     if (cells[x][y] == true) {

       if (numNeighbours > 3 || numNeighbours <= 1) { //underpopulation or overpopulation

       }
     }

     else if (cells[x][y] == false) {

       if (numNeighbours == 3) {

       }
     }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of your code (and the Game of Life), you don't need to store `x` and `y`.  What you actually need to do is to store the `(x, y)` pairs where the cell changes state.

You could do this by creating pairs and adding them to lists.

But a another idea is to use a second array representing the next generation of the game and put all of the new values there; e.g.

```
for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < 30; y++) {
        int numNeighbours = numNeighbours(x,y);
        if (cells[x][y] == true) {
            if (numNeighbours > 3 || numNeighbours <= 1) { 
                cellsNext[x][y] = false;
            } else {
                cellsNext[x][y] = true;
            }   
        }
        else if (cells[x][y] == false) {
            if (numNeighbours == 3) { 
                cellsNext[x][y] = true;
            } else {
                cellsNext[x][y] = false;
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Note: that could be simplified / written better, but I have written it as above so that you can see clearly what I have done.